# psql installation requires systemd

Tags: postgresql, psql, amazon-emr, systemd

I am installing psql on my AWS EMR (EC2 instance) which is Amazon Linux (not Amazon Linux 2).

I am getting an error after running the command

```
sudo yum install -y postgresql10

Error: Package: postgresql10-10.7-2PGDG.rhel7.x86_64 (pgdg10)
           Requires: systemd
```

Amazon Linux 2 comes with systemd but AWS EMR doesn't support Amazon Linux 2.

How can I install psql client on AWS EMR?

Comment: Are you trying to install (only) the `psql` client, or the complete server package?

Comment: only psql client

Comment: Isn't that in the package `postgresql10-client`?

Comment: no. To install server we use postgresql-server but for client we use postgresql only